# I got same error about login and email confirmation code

Tags: php, email, authentication

can sameone tell me what wrong with this code

[image]

```
 <?php if(isset($_SESSION['confirmation_success'])); ?>
               <div class="alert alert-success"> <?php echo $_SESSION['confirmation_success']; ?></div>
                <?php unset($_SESSION['confirmation_success']); ?>
```

code above is login.php line 16

```
function user_login(){
GLOBAL $db;
    if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    $email      = trim($_POST['email']);
    $password   = trim($_POST['password']);
        if(empty($email) || empty($password)){
            echo "<div class = 'alert alert-danger'> please enter email and password</div>";
        }else{
            $Query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?");
            $Query->execute([$email]);
                if($Query->rowCount() == 1){
                    $row = $Query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                    $id = $row->$id;
                    $db_password = $row->password;
                    $status = $row->status;
                        if($status == 0){
                            $_SESSION['user_email'] = $email;
                            $_SESSION['please_confrim'] = "please confirm your email....";
                            header("Location:confirm.php");
                        }else{
                            if(password_verify($password, $db_password)){
                                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $id;
                                header("Location:profile.php");
                            }else{
                                echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>please enter correct password</div>";
                            }
                        }
                }else{
                    echo "<div class ='alert alert-danger'>Please Enter Correct Email</div>";

                }
        }
    }
}
```

code above is function.php can same one help me

Comment: I guess $id = $row->$id; should be $id = $row->id;

Comment: So many errors(

Comment: wow thank but i have one error again

Comment: login.php can you tell me